# Changing my contents in web page in Angular 2 tree view without changing my URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an Angular 2 tree component, and my page is not getting refreshed without changing my URL. Can anyone please help in how to use Angular 2 tree view in change detection?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! You have a much better likelyhood of getting a good answer if you include some information in your question about what you've tried, and why it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Perhaps you want something like a different change detection. I suggest reading [this](https://auth0.com/blog/understanding-angular-2-change-detection/). But, as @TomasLycken said, it'd be better if you provide more information.